# How to skip a node in json comparision

Tags: java, json, algorithm

I have a json comparator

```
class JSONUtils {

public static void areEqual(def context_1, def context_2) {
    Object obj1,obj2;
    Object json = new JSONTokener(context_1).nextValue();
    if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
        obj1 = new JSONObject(context_1);
        obj2 = new JSONObject(context_2);
    } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
        obj1 = new JSONArray(context_1);
        obj2 = new JSONArray(context_2);
    }
    def ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    def JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(obj1.toString());
    def JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(obj2.toString());
    assert tree1.equals(tree2);
   }
 }
```

Which works fine when two json are exactly same. I have a special case where I need to skip or ignore two node values while comparison.

Example:

```
First Json:
{
   "rd":12,
   "td":"text1"
   "dt": 123456,
   "vt": "west"
}
Second Json:
{
   "rd":12,
   "td":"text1"
   "dt": 333333,
   "vt": "east"
}
```

I need to ignore or skip the "dt" and "vt" comparison.

How can I implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom POJO to hold the values you care about:

```
// Ignore fields "dt" and "vt"
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyType {
    // Ideally these should use getters/setters
    public int rd;
    public String td;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MyType) {
            MyType t = (MyType)obj;
            return t.rd == this.rd
                    && Objects.equals(t.td, this.td);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // hashCode() should always be overriden alongside equals()
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(rd, td);
    }
}
```

In your code you can construct and compare them like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyType t1 = mapper.readValue(obj1.toString(), MyType.class);
MyType t2 = mapper.readValue(obj2.toString(), MyType.class);
assert t1.equals(t2);
```

---

Per our discussion in the comments, here's a generic solution to compare any two JSON objects, while filtering out any set of keys, using the Guava library:

```
public static boolean jsonEquals(String json1, String json2, String... ignoreKeys) throws IOException {
    // this is a Guava Predicate
    Predicate<String> filter = Predicates.not(Predicates.in(Sets.newHashSet(ignoreKeys)));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> object1 = Maps.filterKeys(mapper.readValue(json1, Map.class), filter);
    Map<String, Object> object2 = Maps.filterKeys(mapper.readValue(json2, Map.class), filter);
    return object1.equals(object2);
}
```

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.dynatrace.groovysupport.MyType out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [{"id":23,"type":1},{"id":24,"type":1}]; line: 1, column: 1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
 at

Comment: @AllIsWell `[{"id":23,"type":1},{"id":24,"type":1}]` is nothing like what you posted in the question.

Comment: I am trying out for this data  static def context_3 = "[{\"type\": 1,\"id\":23},{\"type\": 1,\"id\":24}]";
 static def context_4 = "[{\"type\": 1,\"id\":23},{\"type\": 1,\"id\":24}]";

Comment: @AllIsWell I created the type based on the JSON in your question. I have no idea what you're trying to show me.

Comment: @AllIsWell Also, you didn't mention anywhere you're using groovy.

Comment: Sorry @shmosel, I really appreciate your response, I have different JSON responses coming as outputs and I have to handle some of the node values while comparison. The one I have asked above is sample output. The node keys might be different too. So I am trying to understand how to implement a method which takes the node keys as inputs and can ignore comparing them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118852/discussion-between-alliswell-and-shmosel).

Comment: finally made it to work. Thanks. One simple adjustment I like to have the same code working for JsonObject and JsonArray.

Comment: @AllIsWell you want to filter values from the array, or keys from objects in the array?

Comment: When I am passing input json array, it throws an error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [{"type": 1,"id":23},{"type": 1,"id":24}]; line: 1, column: 1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148

Comment: @AllIsWell As it should do. You'll need to deserialize to a list or array instead. If you answer my previous question I can try to help.